# Finding P(B=1) using previous given information

Tags: probability

So I have this given information:

P(A = 0) = 1/4

P(B=1 | A=1) = 4/5

P(B=1 | A=0) = 2/5

P(L=0| B=0) = 1/3

P(L=1 | B=1) = 1/4

So my thought process is this:

Bays Thm is this P(A|B) = P(B|A)P(A)/P(B)

To find B:

I could do something like this:

P(B=1|A=0) = x(P(B=1))/P(B=1), where x is P(B=1|A=0)P(A=0)/P(B=1), once I plug everything in and reduce it to find P(B)

Is this the right thought process? Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Which part of the reasoning in the accepted answer was escaping you when you asked the question? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
P(B=1) = P(B=1 | A=1)P(A=1)+ P(B=1 | A=0)P(A=0)$$
hence
$$
 P(B=1) = P(B=1 | A=1)(1-P(A=0))+ P(B=1 | A=0)P(A=0)
$$